# Laravel dropdown of nation column is not working

Tags: laravel

i want to generate dropdown of one column and save in database, here is what i tried but i am getting error.

**View:**

```
<select name="nation_id" class="custom-select" >
<option selected value="">Choose...</option>
  <option value="{{@$teacher->nation->id}}"  {{@$teacher->nation->nation== "{{@$teacher->nation->nation}}" ? 'selected' : ''}} >{{@$teacher->nation->nation}}</option>

 </select>
```

Controller:

```
$teacher->nation_id = $request->nation_id;
$saved = $teacher->save();
return back()->with('message','Record Successfully Updated!');
```

**Comment:**
Teacher is main table, which have column nation_id, and nation is second table which contains list of countries against each id.

Comment: Error: syntax error, unexpected '<'

Comment: What is the line of the error?

Comment: check my comment: syntax error, unexpected '<'

Comment: Which line, where?

Comment: ErrorException (E_ERROR)
syntax error, unexpected '<' (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\todolist\resources\views\teachers\create.blade.php)
Previous exceptions
syntax error, unexpected '<' (0)

Comment: {{$teacher->nation->nation== "{{$teacher->nation->nation}}" ? 'selected' : '{{$teacher->nation->nation}}'

Look at this. You open {{ in the first statment but you never close it

Comment: @MiguelCruz syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting ',' or ')'

Comment: {{@$teacher->nation->nation== "{{@$teacher->nation->nation}}" ? 'selected' : ''}} >{{@$teacher->nation->nation}}

Comment: question updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to use Blade's `{{ }}` echo syntax inside itself, so this line is not valid:

```php
{{@$teacher->nation->nation== "{{@$teacher->nation->nation}}" ? 'selected' : ''}}
```

Anything inside the `{{ }}` echo syntax is raw PHP, so you don't need to use the syntax again - you can simply compare the strings as you would normally:

```php
{{@$teacher->nation->nation== @$teacher->nation->nation ? 'selected' : ''}}
```

However, it looks like you're trying to compare this one value with the same value, so it's always going to return `true` and thus display the option as selected. It looks like your question is incomplete.